# GET Request 2,083 characters Limit and REST APIS

Tags: rest, curl, get, libcurl

I was wondering does the 2,083 characters imposed by certain browsers (looks at IE) affect building `REST APIs`?

Considering the fact that the API request will probably be made from a programmatic interface or library like `CURL` or some other language specific library.

Does this limit also affect programmatically requesting a `GET` resource on the server?

[2083 Characters Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is totally arbitrary and is not originating from any standard or spec. That's also why tools and libraries like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) don't have that limit.

A limit can be valuable to have just to avoid the risk of abuse or various sorts of DOSes that a client could otherwise fall victim to. Exactly what that limit should be is of course subject to debate.

So yes, it *can* certainly affect users of REST APIs if you want to drive them from a browser or if the libs you use have the similar limits (like I would guess perhaps some of the Windows APIs may share the same limits that IE has).